# Inserting into a PostgreSQL table using Perl

Tags: perl, postgresql

I am trying to auto-populate a table in a PostgreSQL database. Unfortunately I am not getting the insert statement to work.

The first row is an ID which is an integer, and the second column is of numeric data type. I am using a Perl script to achieve this.

I am using the `rand` function which creates random numbers between 0 and 1. The first argument is the variable `$id`; the second argument is the variable `$count`.

Based on the count, the table will populate the ID followed by a random number.

I am using PostgreSQL 9.2.4.

```
-ID | Random_Number
-1 |  0.01
-1 |  0.03
-2 |  0.0566

#!/usr/bin/perl

use DBI;

my $id = <>;
my $count = <>;

my $db_host = 'localhost';
my $db_user = 'postgres';
my $db_pass = '12345';
my $db_name = 'postgres';

my $db = "dbi:Pg:dbname=${db_name};host=${db_host}";

$dbh = DBI->connect($db, $db_user, $db_pass, { RaiseError => 1, AutoCommit => 0 })
        || die "Error connecting to the database: $DBI::errstr\n";

for (my $loop = 0; $loop < $count; $loop++) {
    my $random_number = rand();
    my $loop++;
    my $query = "insert into random_table values($loop,$random_number)";
}
```

Comment: Why? This is utterly trivial to do in simple SQL. Is this a test or demo you intend to expand into a real and useful tool later? Also: What's the *problem* you're asking about? PostgreSQL version? Perl version? Platform? **Exact text of any error message**? Close-voting as "not a real question".

Comment: Why do you `my $loop++;` when `$loop` is already being managed by your `for` loop? And why not use `$dbh->prepare` and placeholders? And specifying your columns in your INSERTs is a good idea.

Comment: To do this in SQL: `CREATE TABLE demo(id serial primary key, randnum float);` then `insert into demo(randnum) select random() from generate_series(1,100);` . (You can use `generate_series` to supply the IDs rather than using sequence-generated IDs if preferred). Doing this in a single SQL query will be *immensely* faster than looping in Perl. Avoid looping over SQL calls if at all possible.

Comment: @Craig Ringer: I need to have the ID based on the argument i provide. Its ok if its a duplicate value. I am trying to auto populate a table. Trying my hand at testing.

Comment: @user2272525 Then `insert into demo(id, randnum) select x, random() from generate_series($start,$start+$count) x;` and define the `id` column as `integer` instead of `serial`.

Comment: You don't appear to be executing any SQL. That would certainly explain why nothing is being inserted into your database :/

Answer (score 2):

This is unnecessarily complex. Just:

```
CREATE TABLE random_table(id integer, random_value float);
```

then:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect($db, $db_user, $db_pass,{ RaiseError => 1, AutoCommit => 0 })
my $sth $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO random_table(id,random_value) SELECT x, random() FROM generate_series(?,?);")
my $result = $sth->execute(0, $count);
```

(Untested but I'm pretty sure that's right).

BTW, you *really* need to:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.10.1; // or whatever the oldest Perl you support is
```

in your scripts.

Answer (score 1):

First, you are redeclaring the $loop variable, which will mask its previous declaration. Since ++ on an undefined value = 1, $loop in $query is 1 each time.

```
for(my $loop=0; $loop < $count;$loop++)
{
  my $random_number = rand();
  my $loop++; # Shouldn't be here
  my $query = "insert into random_table values($loop,$random_number)";
}
```

If you had turned warnings on perl would have warned you about this.

Second, you are doing nothing with $query. It's just a string. You have to execute it, e.g. $dbh->do($query).